# how to set up recurring billing for paypal payment yii?

Tags: php, yii, paypal, yii-extensions, recurring-billing

My sites's functionality is of member subscription -monthly/annually and i want automated paypal payments(recurring).

I have used "easyPayPal yii extension" for Paypal payments on my site,
its running fine for one time payments but I want to add support for recurring payments in it and i don't have much idea about it as I am a newbie to Paypal integration and using yii.

so was hoping  if someone can help me out.
I have posted link to the extension I have used and also the Paypal response I get on successful payment of transaction.

extension link that i have used
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/easypaypal/

Response from paypal on transaction success:

```
/*
          Below you can see a sample successfull response of a payment process from paypal
         Array
          (
              [TOKEN] => EC-1AG000796M3683304
              [SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED] => false
              [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-12-12T11:57:17Z
              [CORRELATIONID] => 89a33a155e512
              [ACK] => Success
              [VERSION] => 65.1
              [BUILD] => 8725992
              [TRANSACTIONID] => 7S255873FM437633X
              [TRANSACTIONTYPE] => expresscheckout
              [PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
              [ORDERTIME] => 2013-12-12T11:57:17Z
              [AMT] => 1800.00
              [FEEAMT] => 52.50
              [TAXAMT] => 0.00
              [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
              [PAYMENTSTATUS] => Completed
              [PENDINGREASON] => None
              [REASONCODE] => None
              [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Eligible
              [INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED] => false
              [SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT] => false
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID] => 7S255873FM437633X
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE] => expresscheckout
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME] => 2013-12-12T11:57:17Z
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT] => 1800.00
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT] => 52.50
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS] => Completed
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON] => None
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE] => None
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Eligible
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
              [PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK] => Success
          )

        */
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and you can check the following posts:

[How to set mixture of recurring and one time payment in Paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997058/how-to-set-mixture-of-recurring-and-one-time-payment-in-paypal)

[Recurring payment IPN request rp_invoice_id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037028/recurring-payment-ipn-request-rp-invoice-id-field)

[Recurring payments billing period problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337705/recurring-payments-billing-period-problems)

You can find good REST API API library [here](https://github.com/amirduran/duranius-paypal-rest-api-php-library). It is well documented and it is working fine. It supports recurring payments too.