# Recurring payment IPN request rp_invoice_id field

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Here is example of PayPal Express Checkout Recurring Payment IPN request:

```
 [mc_gross] => 6.56
    [period_type] =>  Regular
    [outstanding_balance] => 0.00
    [next_payment_date] => 03:00:00 Jun 21, 2012 PDT
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [payment_cycle] => Weekly
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_id] => K48P3Fxxxx
    [payment_date] => 16:52:28 Jun 14, 2012 PDT
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [product_name] => Virtual Subscription &#36;6.56 / week for 3 weeks
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [rp_invoice_id] => 208
    [recurring_payment_id] => I-4DHKxxxx
    [first_name] => Test
    [mc_fee] => 0.38
    [notify_version] => 3.4
    [amount_per_cycle] => 6.56
    [payer_status] => verified
    [currency_code] => USD
    [business] => xxxx@gmail.com
    [verify_sign] => AlAlnsACWRTf4OV6vRMZG4sCyEdYACBnr7ishagKt60BxtlJgPjaRIAh
    [payer_email] => xxxx@gmail.com
    [initial_payment_amount] => 0.00
    [profile_status] => Active
    [amount] => 6.56
    [txn_id] => 3PE0612xxxx
    [payment_type] => instant
    [last_name] => User
    [receiver_email] => xxxx@gmail.com
    [payment_fee] => 0.38
    [receiver_id] => TYDEKWLxxxx
    [txn_type] => recurring_payment
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [residence_country] => US
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [transaction_subject] => Virtual Subscription &#36;6.56 / week for 3 weeks
    [payment_gross] => 6.56
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [product_type] => 1
    [time_created] => 23:48:22 Jun 13, 2012 PDT
    [ipn_track_id] => b2c853ddxxxx
```

As you can see, there is field called `rp_invoice_id` which is *The merchant’s own unique reference or invoice number, which can be  used to uniquely identify a profile.*

When creating API call `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`, how to pass this value, which field should I set in the API call?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the PROFILEREFERENCE parameter to pass in a value that will be returned via IPN in the rp_invoice_id parameter.

> PROFILEREFERENCE
>
> (Optional) The merchant's own unique reference or invoice number.
>
> Character length and limitations: 127 single-byte alphanumeric characters

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Exactly what I searched for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It will not work like this, newer versions of API are using REST calls.

To make this working you have to first download Paypal SDK. It is available at http://paypal.github.io/sdk/

Make sure you use official version of SDK, there might be chances that you may use different version and someone may be sitting there to steal your valuable information. My suggestion is before start working go through original documentation, to have an idea.

Once you install SDK, then you could use the example given in the link below

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/recurring_payment_cc/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

This will make API call.

Also you can try with complete documentation available at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

Happy Coding!
Atul Jindal

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer? Any particular reason why it should not work by calling NVP API?

Comment: It will work just fine.  This is incorrect information.  I'll post an answer shortly.