# Recurring payments billing period problems

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

We have implemented PayPal recurring payment functionality on our website. During the subscription checkout, users have option to check automatic payment which will charge them every 1 year.

After `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API method is called and finished, we call `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` API method with the following details:

```
$requestParams=array(
                    "TOKEN"=>$token,
                    "PROFILESTARTDATE"=>date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"),
                    "DESC"=>"Mimi subscription",
                    "BILLINGPERIOD"=>"Year",
                    "BILLINGFREQUENCY"=>"1",
                    "AMT"=>$subscriptionType->price,
                    "CURRENCYCODE"=>"GBP",
                    "PROFILEREFERENCE"=>$transactionId

                );
```

where the TOKEN is the value returned from the `SetExpressCheckout` API metod call. We set `PROFILESTARTDATE` to today's date (13 Oct 2014), `BILLINGPERIOD` to Year and `BILLINGFREQUENCY` to 1.

When we test this code, everything seems to be working fine, and recurring payment profile is created, but the following detail is interesting. When I enter to my sandbox account, in my recurring payments profiles I can see the profile previously created. Here is image attached:

[image]

Why the *Next payment due* date is today's date (we did testing on 13th October 2014), and why it is not set to 13 Oct 2015? Is this means that user will be charged 2 times in 2014 (once during normal subscription checkout and then once using recurring payment profile mechanism).

Thx in advance.

Comment: Isn't it possible to set a next payment date for the subscription?

Comment: How do you mean? We want automatic transactions every one year and that is it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already charged the buyer for the year 2014 using the "DoExpressCheckout" API then you need to specify the "PROFILESTARTDATE" as "13 Oct 2015". "PROFILESTARTDATE" specifies when the profile is going to be charged , So in your case it should be charged once again and then on "13 Oct 2015".

Comment: Makes no sense. Profiles are automatic. Something is broken there.